# Does Intel xdk / Jquery Mobile work with Parse.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, parse-platform, intel-xdk

If I build a cross-platform app using the Intel XDK or jQuery mobile, would I still be able to use Parse.com as a back-end to manage data in the cloud and push notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, but only up to the point, and to make it clear, I'm talking from jQuery Mobile perspective.

You application will use Parse.com **REST API** for communication but that's about it. Because you are creating a hybrid mobile app **RESTFul** (AJAX) connection is only viable solution.

You can of course go for some native solution, using Java (Android) or Objective C (iOS)  but you will need to write your own wrapper code that will communicate with JavaScript. This is a bad solution because it brakes the point of hybrid mobile applications (One solution to rule them all).

To incorporate everything you will need **Cordova** (**PhoneGap**) as mobile app wrapper. From my knowledge, Phonegap plugin is still no go, so you will need to create your own implementation, which will not be that hard, if you take into account that Phonegap plugin for classic push notifications exist, and you can use **RESTFul** communication to feed it data.

Also, why limit yourself to those two frameworks? Faster, more native like frameworks exist, so choose wisely (find more information [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/top-7-mobile-application-html5-frameworks/)). Application speed if your first and major concern.

Leave me a comment if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **[Intel XDK](http://xdk.intel.com)** is an HTML5 Development Environment to develop HTML5 Mobile Apps, you can use any HTML5 framework like jQuery Mobile and use Parse.com for back-end for data, for push notification you will have to install Cordova plugin, which is currently not supported in the current version, but will be available soon.